# Passing arguments to a library loaded with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: linux, ld-preload

Is it possible to pass arguments to my library, which is loaded with `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
LD_PRELOAD=lib.so ./program
```

How can I pass arguments to this library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I'd do this by using environment variables. For example with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init() __attribute__ ((constructor));
void init() {
  std::cout << "Init: " << getenv("MYLIB") << std::endl;
}
```

lets you do:

```
MYLIB=hi LD_PRELOAD=./test.so /bin/echo
Init: hi
```

this doesn't have to be used in a constructor (which is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)), but that's often a handy place to use them.

What I've done in the past has been to use this, combined with a shell script wrapper that looks like it's a "normal" application. The shell script takes its arguments and pushes them into the environment variables your library expects before calling `exec` to load the program you want to interpose. It "feels" right to users that way without being too fragile or intrusive.

You could also do this by reading `/proc/self/cmdline` to read the command line of the current process directly if you'd rather. Personally I'd keep clear of interfering with the process you're working with as much as possible though.

Comment: @ChercheurChercheur that's fine - I only used iostreams for printing, you can trivially make it into stdio and there's nothing else C++ specific besides that. (The constructor attribute works in C, it calls the function automatically when the library gets loaded, not a C++ constructor)

Comment: Please, i want to pass more that one argument to my lib, is that possible?

Comment: @ChercheurChercheur - use multiple environment variables or pass a list in through the environment variable.

Comment: i do like that for example: MYLIB=hi,hello LD_PRELOAD=./test.so /bin/echo
 ?

Comment: @ChercheurChercheur - yes that would be one way, or you could do `MYLIBARG1=val1 MYLIBARG2=val2 LD_PRELOAD=./test.so /bin/bech` or make the single list name/value pairs: `MYLIB='k1=v1:k2=v2' LD_PRELOAD ...`